# Can anyone help me with this please? I have to take backup of my Windows

Tags: windows, backup, error-handling, disk-management

[image]

Can anyone help me with this please? I have to take backup of my Windows.

Comment: It's a non-native file-system (NTFS) thus is best handled within windows itself.  Errors were detected in the file-system, meaning the disk has issues, it was left in an *unclean* state (used on a system with fast-boot enabled, or like form of hibernation active) thus should be repaired in windows (or replaced if hardware error) before being used in GNU/Linux.   The issue is either hardware or the OS that wrote it didn't complete all writes (fastboot/hibernate etc) & should safely-complete writes.

Comment: Try booting in Windows, disabling fast startup, and then try again

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions are available in the very dialog you show. The file system is inconsistent. Thus, connect it to MS Windows, then have it checked using the Windows drive checking tools (you can, if you wish, use the Windows command line tool chkdsk like the message says). Then close Windows completely after having disabled "faststart" in Windows. That ensures that Windows will fully close the file system when shutting down. Only when an ntfs file system is healthy and clean will Ubuntu seamlessly access it.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much.